# optimize $x^2+y$ on the constraint that $x^2-y^3=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, constraints

Problem: Find maximum and minimum value for the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y$ on the constraint $x^2-y^3=0$.

My Solution:

I have started solving this by using the Lagrange method to find points where the gradients are perpendicular and where the points are also satisfied by the constraint.

I get (by solving for when the determinant that holds the two gradients is zero) the equation $-2x(3y^2+1)=0$.

So this gives me first with $-2x=0$ and the constraint $x^2-y^3=0$ the system of equations:
$$x=0$$
$$x^2-y^3=0$$
Which gives me the point $(0,0)$ with value $f(0,0)=0$

With $3y^2+1=0$ and the constraint I get:
$$y^2=-1/3$$
$$x^2-y^3=0$$

Questions:

- My question for the second system of equation is: with $y^2=-1/3$ does this mean that there is no solution? Or did I do something wrong?
- The constraint is not a compact set of value, it is not bounded? My textbook gives the answer to this problem as minimum value is 0 and maximum does not exist. How can I prove this and how do I know that 0 is the minimum and not the maximum value?

Comment: You did fine. As $y^2=-1/3$ hasn't got any real solutions, it simply fails to produce more candidate points.

Comment: Non-compactness of the set defined by the constraint equation leaves open the possibility that the function has neither constrained minima nor maxima. Can you prove that $y\ge0$ whenever the constraint holds? And therefore also____? So the candidate point you did find gives a constrained ______?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Im not sure how to prove y bigger or equal to zero. y^3 = x^2 in the constraint.

Comment: $x^2\ge0$. Therefore ____?

Comment: Got it! But i need not to say anything about an upper bound? The fact that i proved that the Only candidate point I found is the minimum value proves there is no max?

Comment: I think that the lack of other candidate points does prove the non-existence of a maximum., but that is a bit subtle (could fail in a superficially similar situation). IMO a more convincing way of doing that is to show that $x^2+y$ takes arbitrarily large values on the constraint set. Like if $x=10^{3k}$ and $y=10^{2k}$, then the constraint holds and $f(x,y)>10^{6k}$. That's arbitrarily large as we can choose $k$ any which way we want. $\implies$ no maximum. Just give $x$ some high value, and show that a matching positive $y$ exists then $f(x,y)_x^2$ will become large.

Comment: Alternatively use the parametrization from Lab Bhattacharjee's answer. I actually used it above :-)

Answer (score 1):

WLOG $x=t^3,y=t^2$

$x^2+y=t^6+t^2=t^2(t^4+1)\ge0$

Comment: How did you get x=t^3, y =t^2. Is it from x^2-y^3?

Comment: Yes. You can set $t=y/x$. Plug that in, and solve the constraint. This was my first thought (the parametrization of this curve is kinda well known). But, you asked about using Lagrange multipliers.... Nevertheless, had I assigned this problem to a class I couldn't resist bringing this up :-)